# Исключить дубликаты в запросе

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

имеется запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

реализовано первое предложение.

```
  select req1.n_post, req1.n_izd, req1.sum, req2.max
   --ищем всех поставщиков, которые поставили максимум для изделия
  from (select --ищем все суммы
        n_post, n_izd, sum(kol)
        from spj
        group by n_izd, n_post
        ) req1
  join (select --ищем максимальную сумму для изделия
        n_izd, max(tmp.sum)
        from (select --ищем все суммы(был выше)
              n_post, n_izd, sum(kol)
              from spj
              group by n_izd, n_post
              ) tmp
        group by n_izd
        ) req2
  on req1.n_izd=req2.n_izd
  where sum=max
  order by 1
```

с результатом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как исполнить эти 'если' не могу понять.
Как отсюда исключить дубликаты по n_izd (строка 1 и 2) на основании сравнения значении строк?

Исходные таблицы
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKxQ8.jpg)

Comment: Один `distinct on` после группировки по изделию, поставщику.

Comment: Нарисуёте хотя бы схему Вашей базы. Ничего не понятно из Вашего запроса. По моему тут join ни к чему.

Comment: Добавил исходные таблички

Answer (score 0):

Довольно сложно понять обозначения, но зачем вам удалять дубликаты если нужно выбрать только одного поставщика? Можно ведь поставить в конце `LIMIT 1` и получить того самого, первого по алфавиту.

PS:я не могу коментировать, поэтому пишу здесь(